# ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3' in python3.3

Tags: django, sqlite, python-3.3

sqlite3 error

```
import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 26, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

i use sqlite3 install command

```
pip install pysqlite
Downloading/unpacking pysqlite
  Downloading pysqlite-2.6.3.tar.gz (76kB): 76kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pysqlite
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/codecs.py", line 300, in decode
        (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 98: invalid continuation byte 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/codecs.py", line 300, in decode

    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 98: invalid continuation byte

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pysqlite
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Do you have libsqlite3-dev installed?

Comment: Try importing it outside of django. What happens?

Comment: yes already installed libsqlite3-dev

Comment: python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 29, in <module>

Comment: I can not answer :(((
I do not have enough to Ranked :((

Comment: What platform? Do you have sqlite3 otherwise installed, say with homebrew or apt?

Comment: Follow below steps 1) wget https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-autoconf-3310100.tar.gz 2) tar xvf sqlite-autoconf-3310100.tar.gz
3) cd sqlite-autoconf-3310100/
4) ./configure --prefix=/usr
5) make install 6) Re-compile Python 3.X.X. Be sure run "make clean" before "make install" if you've already installed

Answer (score 35):

I am a Fedora 20 user. To solve this:

1. Install sqlite-devel package, using:

   ```
   yum install sqlite-devel
   ```
2. After installing,recompile python from the source using:

   ```
   ./configure
   make && make install
   ```

For multiple versions of Python, use `altinstall` instead of `install`.

Comment: I have no idea why this got two downvotes.  It solved the problem on CentOS 5.11.

Comment: Where is the configure file? I've tried `find /*/python*/conf*` but found nothing.

Comment: This is a great answer. Just worked for me on RHEL 6.7 (Santiago).

Comment: reasonable answer! Worked on the CentOS 7!

Answer (score 12):

I think it must be you not install sqlite3, you can do like this

```
 sudo apt-get install sqlite3  
 sqlite3 -version  
 sudo apt-get install python-pysqlite2  
 sudo apt-get install python-pysqlite2-dbg  
 sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev   
 sudo apt-get install sqlite  
 sudo pip install pysqlite
```

then you will will find the sqlite3

Comment: This worked for me : https://www.markgruenberg.site/doku.php?id=python:sqlite3_not_installed_on_python_centos_or_rhat

Comment: Thanks, `libsqlite3-dev` is the missing key for me.

Comment: I don't understand what sorcery is this but it does work !

Answer (score 9):

For Python3 in Ubuntu:

- `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`
- `wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.3/Python-3.6.3.tar.xz` (replace the version number by your python3 version)
- `tar -xf Python-3.6.3.tar.xz`
- `cd Python-3.6.3/`
- `./configure --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions && make && sudo make install`

refer: https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues/173

Comment: Beware that "make install" is not recommended as it may overwrite your system's Python version and some packages might depend on specific versions. It is recommended to use "make altinstall" to not overwrite /usr/bin/python3 but install it into /usr/local/bin/python3. See https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/unix.html#building-python for details!

Answer (score 7):

The compile package is short of something,you should use yum to 
install these 5,and then recompile and install python3

```
yum install readline-devel
yum install tk-devel
yum install tcl-devel  
yum install openssl-devel   
yum install sqlite-devel
```

and then recompile the python3

```
tar Jxvf  Python-3.5.0.tar.xz
cd Python-3.5.0
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python3
make && make install
```

Answer (score 3):

I touched this problem in using compiled 3.5.7

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.7/Python-3.5.7.tgz
tar xvfz Python-3.5.7.tgz
cd Python-3.5.7
./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
```

```
# python3.5
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

#### Solution:

```
yum install sqlite-devel
re-compile python 3.5 from source
```

Comment: I installed sqlite-devel before second recompile, this might solve the problem.  `yum install sqlite-devel`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below url to get ride of this error,
[Centos-Sqlite3-Error-GCP](https://kalaivairamuthu.wordpress.com/2022/10/10/centos-sqlite3-import-error-while-running-docker-command-with-gcp/)