# Import error with Ubuntu script using newspaper module

Tags: python, ubuntu, lxml, python-import, python-newspaper

I have a script that will run locally, but not on my Ubuntu server. Other scripts work fine on both platforms, but this specific one throws a import error when I attempt to run it on Ubuntu.

```
root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:~# /usr/bin/python3.5 /opt/script_folder/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/script_folder/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import process
  File "/opt/script_folder/process.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tools.getImages import getImages
  File "/opt/script_folder/tools/getImages.py", line 5, in <module>
    from newspaper import Article
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/newspaper/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .api import (build, build_article, fulltext, hot, languages,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/newspaper/api.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .article import Article
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/newspaper/article.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import network
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/newspaper/network.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .configuration import Configuration
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/newspaper/configuration.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .parsers import Parser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/newspaper/parsers.py", line 10, in <module>
    import lxml.etree
ImportError: No module named 'lxml.etree'
```

Other scripts work fine and I didn't have this problem until I tried using the newspaper library. I have attempted the following:

- pip3 install --upgrade newspaper3k
- pip3 install --upgrade lxml
- adding */usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages* to $PATH
- running on and off of a virtual environment
- importing lxml.etree directly within the script
- running on python3.5 terminal - 
  [no errors thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISpnv.jpg)
- apt-get remove python3.5,
  pip3 uninstall newspaper3k,
  pip3 install newspaper3k,
  apt-get install python3.5
- checked permissions of site-packages folder
- checked the default library path that python3.5 uses
- ensured the hashbang *#!/usr/bin/env python3.5* is at the top of all files
- sudo apt-get install python-lxml

I'm stumped here. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

---

EDIT:
I have also followed the instructions listed here: https://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Everything downloaded correctly except the following:

```
root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:~# curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codelucas/newspaper/master/download_corpora.py | python3
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     100   657  100   657    0     0   9387      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 10265
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    from nltk.stem import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/stem/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/stem/snowball.py", line 32, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/corpus/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus.reader import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus.reader.panlex_lite import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/panlex_lite.py", line 15, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing lxml module in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598229/installing-lxml-module-in-python)

Comment: I've attempted all solutions in the above question, and still no luck

Answer (score 0):

based on your post, it seems like the problem can be with ubuntu environment differing from your other (mac os?) local environments. I assume that you've gotten newspaper3k lib to install properly on Mac OS environments but not Ubuntu?

Perhaps try the guidance in this post first, [ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3' in python3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126475/importerror-no-module-named-sqlite3-in-python3-3/25721685)

I think the core issue is that your ubuntu env is missing some important underlying packages that these python libs require.

Or maybe:

 `apt-get install sqlite3

 sqlite3 -version

 apt-get install python-pysqlite2

 apt-get install python-pysqlite2-dbg

 apt-get install libsqlite3-dev

 apt-get install sqlite

 pip install pysqlite`